# Reactjs: Child Functional Component Must Refer to 'Global' Array

Tags: reactjs, scope, global

I'm trying to design a React App to manipulate an inventory database. To add items to the inventory, I've created a functional component `ItemAddForm`.

`ItemAddForm` (and many future functional components) needs to refer to an array `itemTypes`. How should and where should `itemTypes` be declared? I want to avoid passing `itemTypes` as a prop to every single component, but I don't know if Context can be used for Arrays? Should `itemTypes` be global and if so how does one declare a global variable in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, yes, you CAN use Arrays in contexts. However, be very careful using contexts as any changes to contexts will cause all child components that consume the context to re-render.

That said, your two options really are context or props. There's no "global variable" in React. You can set the state in the lowest common denominator shared between components that need the information and then share it via props or context from there. The only other alternative would be to create a javascript file that has the array and export the data from there. However, this would be a static file and you would have to import that file in each component which is probably more of a pain than just passing props down.

Answer (score 1):

> if Context can be used for Arrays

Yes, you can use the Context API to pass arrays, objects, functions or primitive types.

> I want to avoid passing itemTypes as a prop to every single component.

Then, you need to use either **Redux** or the **Context API**. If your variable will not change too frequently you can you can use Context API.

> where should itemTypes be declared?

You can define Context Provider in one of the common parents of the components which will consume the data.